# Shadow not showing up

Tags: shadow, css

I am trying to place shadows in one of the div and it's not showing up.  Here is one div where I am trying to implement the shadow:

```
#intro {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    float:inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 800px;
    position:inherit;
    background-color: #00b3e1;; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 205):

The reason you can't see the shadow is because the next div (#one) is directly below it, and the shadow is rendering beneath #one.  Remove the background image from #one and the shadow becomes visible.

Add this to #intro's CSS to make the shadow visible:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
```

If you want shadows visible on the other text areas, you'll need to adjust their z-index values as well, with the top element (#intro) having the highest value.

Comment: position: relative did it for me.

Comment: Excellent. I didn't need to give a z-index, relative position worked! Thank you! I had spent an hour trying to figure out the issue.

Comment: position: relative did it for me.

Comment: z-index (with increasing values for divs whose shadow should be on top of another div) is needed if you have more than 2 divs, each with its shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Another scenario which I had today. Box-shadow was not showing up in spite of setting position relative to the div. Apparently there was no content next to this div which had box shadow.

Once the content was added, box-shadow showed up.